# Pie and margin inside nvd3 chart

Tags: margin, nvd3.js

I have problem with too small size circle inside pie chart

How to margin to 0 between circle and legend?
Thank you
Dmitry

```
rwt.chart.register("nv-pie", function(widget) {
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
.x(function(d) { return d.label })
.y(function(d) { return d.value; })
.showLabels(true)
.labelType("value")
.showLegend(true)
.donut(true)         
.donutRatio(0.35)
.pieLabelsOutside (false)
.legendPosition("right")
.valueFormat(function(d) { return Math.round(d);});
```

[My pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOOeL.png)

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score -1):

If you want modify margin between chart and legend you can try to use this property:

```
chart.legend.margin({top: 0, right: -20, bottom: 20, left: 0});
```

In this way you can handle every margin.

I made a simple example for you https://jsfiddle.net/s5hj83L4/2/.

Let me know.

Regards